# Any good way to slow a function call in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to implement a slow effect to original bee's action below. With which, after the effect applied each time, the bee will do nothing when colony.time is odd, otherwise do original action, for 'duration' turns.

Please be noted below codes are not fully correct but add my thoughts in it.

My thought is to use a list to temporary hold the effects applied, but don't know how and where to add the effects.pop(0). Simply check the length of the effects and pop the effect in bee's action seem not working, as make_slow function needs to call original action.

I've been stuck here for days. Could anyone give some idea how to deal with such slow effect? Big thanks in advance.

```
class Colony:
    def __init__(self, bee, ant):
        self.bee = bee
        self.ant = ant
        self.time = 0


class Bee:
    name = 'bee'
    def __init__(self, armor=5):
        self.armor = armor

    def action(self, colony):
        self.sting(colony.ant)

    def sting(self, target):
        target.reduce_armor(1)

    def reduce_armor(self, n):
        self.armor -= n
        if self.armor <= 0:
            self.armor = 0

class Ant:
    name = 'ant'
    def __init__(self, armor=5):
        self.armor = armor

    def throw_at(self, target):
        target.reduce_armor(1)

    def action(self, colony):
        self.throw_at(colony.bee)

    def reduce_armor(self, n):
        self.armor -= n
        if self.armor <= 0:
            self.armor = 0

effects = [] # hope to use this list to hold all effects, but might be some other better ways

def make_slow(action):
    """Return a new action method that calls ACTION every other turn.
    After the effect, the bee will do nothing where colony.time is odd, otherwise do original action.
    action -- An action method of some Bee
    """
    def f(duration): # to be discussed. 
        a = lambda colony: action(colony) if not colony.time % 2 else None
        effects.extend([a] * 2 * duration)
    return f

def apply_effect(effect, bee, duration):
    """Apply a status effect to a BEE that lasts for DURATION turns."""
    effect(bee.action)(duration)

class ThrowerAnt(Ant):
    """ThrowerAnt that causes Slow on Bees."""
    def throw_at(self, target):
        if target:
            apply_effect(make_slow, target, 2)


bee = Bee()
ant = ThrowerAnt()
colony = Colony(bee, ant)
ant.action(colony) # apply slow effect to bee's action
colony.time += 1
bee.action(colony) # colony.time is odd, bee will do nothing
colony.time += 1
bee.action(colony) # colony.time is even, bee will do original action, turn #1
colony.time += 1
bee.action(colony) # colony.time is odd, bee will do nothing
colony.time += 1
bee.action(colony) # colony.time is even, bee will do original action, turn #2
colony.time += 1
bee.action(colony) # run out of effects, bee will do original action
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using the power of sleep function in time module

```
import time
time.sleep(60) # this will delay for 1 minute
```

Comment: Thanks, but add a time delay is not what I need here. I want the bee's action slow down if the ant applies the slow effect. As the codes show, the bee's action stops by turns when the colony.time is odd.